# How to get the dist version of an AngularJS project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I tried building dist version of my project using the command **gulp**. It built the dist version but when I try running it in the browser it's not working.

But when my friend did this in his system, he is able to do this. I am not able to find the solution why it's not working with me. When I checked the versions:

npm = 3.9.5

node = 3.9.5

nvm = 0.33.0

My friends:

```
npm -v = 3.10.8
node -v = 6.2.2
nvm --version = 0.11.1
```

Is this because of the versions?

Answer (score 0):

can try to update version of node and npm with this command: npm install npm@latest -g

and check the angular version with this command: ng -v

if not working contact me again

Bye